# Wpf binding not working when notifying property change without assigning new instance to property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

So, I have this very simle code,  and when I click on a button while using the commented line of code, the value in GUI is through a binding updated and everything is ok. If I use the other two lines (uncomented), nothing happens even though I am notifing change.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Spot _position = new Spot(0, 0);
    public Spot Position
    {
        get { return _position; }
        set { _position = value; OnPropertyChanged("Position"); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        win.DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Position = new Spot(5,5);
        Position.UpdateX(5);
        OnPropertyChanged("Position");
    }
}

public class Spot
{
    public Spot(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public void UpdateX(int x)
    {
        X += x;
    }
    public void UpdateY(int y)
    {
        Y += y;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}; {1}", X, Y);
    }

    public int X { get; set; } = 0;
    public int Y { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

XAML

```
<StackPanel x:Name="win" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="100">
    <Label Content="{Binding Position, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100" Height="25"></Label>
    <Button Width="100" Height="25" Click="Button_Click">Click</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: When you run Position.UpdateX(5), you are updating X and not the position. Thefore it does not work. Implement PropertyChanged on X and it will work. And there won't be any need for this line OnPropertyChanged("Position");.

Comment: Those two uncommented lines work for me.

Comment: @adminSoftDK I knew it could be fixed like that, and to combat it I added the additional notify. Also, I don't want to mess up the Spot class with UI code.

Comment: Having NotifyPropertyChanged in your model is fine, it has nothing to do with the UI code. You can extract a base for your INPC implementation and just inherit from it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett huh, are you sure? if I click the button with them the text in my binded textbox remains 0; 0 insted of 5; 0.

Comment: @TeddParsile I copied `Spot` verbatim, made a `Spot` property of a `MainWindow` that implements `INPC`, etc. Best approximation I can manage based on what you posted. But it's not 100% identical your code, obviously.

Comment: `win.DataContext` is a typo right?

Comment: @EdPlunkett yeah, but it still doesn't work

Comment: What does the UI XAML look like where `Position` is displayed?

Comment: @EdPlunkett added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Label Content="{Binding Position}" ... />
```

What this will do is call `ToString()` on `Position` every time the viewmodel raises the `PropertyChanged` event to report that the value of `Position` has changed. That is, if a *new object instance has been assigned to the `Position` property*. You can sit there all day assigning new values to the properties of the old instance, and the viewmodel doesn't know that's happening so no event is raised.

This will work:

```
<Label>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}: {1}">
                <Binding Path="Position.X" />
                <Binding Path="Position.Y" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</Label>
```

This will work too:

```
<Label>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position.X, StringFormat='{}{0}: '}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position.Y}" />
    </TextBlock>
</Label>
```